# Firebase TestLab Report: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab, android-vitals

A Critical Exception causes the app to abort and may therefore return the user to the operating system home screen.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: XXXXX
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.app.MainActivity$19
    at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:421)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

but am not getting the above issue in development environment

Comment: There's not much to go on here. Best is to talk to the Test Lab engineers directly about this. Join the Firebase Slack in the #test-lab channel [firebase.community](https://firebase.community/). Post your matrix-id and the team can take a look on what is going on.